# How cut datetime trom received data in python

Tags: python, sockets, datetime

I've got datetime server that sends data as:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today() 
data = bytearray(today.ctime(), encoding="utf8")  
data.extend('z' * (length-len(data)))
```

In client aplication I want to print only received date and time, without "z" letters. My only idea is to search for first "z" letter and print to the moment when program finds it. Is there more "elegant" way to do it?

Comment: Can you give an example of a string sent by the server ?

Comment: "Fri Aug 24 16:39:12 2018 zzzzzzzzzzzzzz"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways to do this:

You can simply replace all z by an empty character and remove the final space.

```
data = "Fri Aug 24 16:39:12 2018 zzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
data = data.replace('z','')[:-1]
```

Or you can split the string based on spaces, remove the last element and concatenate the remaining ones.

```
' '.join(data.split()[:-1])
```